# Chance to disable picture loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to prevent (with jQuery) certain images from being loaded by a mobile device? Is there already a jQuery plugin?

For example: I want all images with the class "toobig" to not being loaded by a mobile device.

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to *prevent* them from loading, but you could simply change the attributes of those elements in order to *change* what the browser attempts to load:

```
$('img.toobig')
    .attr({'width' : 0, 'height' : 0, 'src' : 'path/to/small/image.png'})
    .hide();
```

The above finds the relevant images, gives them a `height` and `width` of `0` (so the layout engine can flow/reflow the document quickly, and gives an `src` to, ideally, a small transparent image file. Of course, you could simply `removeAttr('src')`, if you prefer.

The call to `hide()` at the end is simply to ensure that, even with the size of `0`, there's no way for the images to show in the document. In this case `remove()` could, of course, be used instead.

Comment: Thank you for the details! If I use 
`$(document).ready(function(){
// your code
});` will the browser do it before the images start loading?

Comment: It should do; though there's no way to be entirely sure. We can only be certain that `$(document).ready()` fires, and so *begins*, before image-loading is complete. However, if you put the code in a `<script></script>` block at the foot of the page, *outside of* a `$(document).ready()` then it'll start as soon the browser encounters that script.

Comment: Thanks! In a initial test with an iPad it worked as intented! As i was searching for a simple solution, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but I'd suggest only loading them when you know it's not mobile like so:

```
$('.toobig').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="'+$(this).data('src')+'" />');
});
```

Where you have something like spans to represent the images you don't want loading on mobile with a data attribute of 'src', like so:

```
<span class="toobig" data-src="/your/location/image.jpg"></span>
```

You could extend this to add things like alt text and so fourth.

Comment: thanks you, but they should not be replaced - just vanish :) i want to reduce the amount to load on a mobile device.

Will this work?
`$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.toobig').each(function() {
  $(this).remove();
  });
});`

Comment: That will remove the images, but they will still be loaded, thus the mobile users will waste data. The code I supplied above should be executed when you know it's not a mobile device.